# Как вкомпилировать одну библиотеку в другую?

Tags: c++, cmake, сборка, линковка, conan

Делаю библиотеку А, которая использует protobuf для сериализации. Собираю из неё conan пакет, чтобы использовать в других приложениях. Protobuf используется как внутренняя библиотека - в интерфейсе библиотеки А не используется protobuf, или его message'и.
Protobuf подключаю следующим образом:

```
target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE ${PROTOBUF_LIB})
```

Библиотека А собирается и проходит тесты, но при линковке в другой проект возникает ошибка:

```
~/.conan/data/protobuf/3.9.1/../include/google/protobuf/arena.h:531: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Arena::OnArenaAllocation(std::type_info const*, unsigned long) const'
```

Как я понял, protobuf линкуется, но его код не встраивается в код бибилотеки А.
Учитывая, что наружу библиотеки не торчит ничего из porotobuf - можно ли подключить его так, чтобы убрать его из зависимостей? Что-то наподобии подключения статичской библиотеки в код другой библиотеки?

Comment: Ну так и надо линковать статическую библиотеку protobuf.

Comment: @user7860670 А если пользователь библиотеки А захочет использовать protobuf другой версии - в проекте будут две версии одной библиотеки и это же должно вызвать конфликт?

Comment: У него будет только библиотека А и его версия protobuf. А о том, что в A тоже используется protobuf он не узнает, так как эта библиотека не является частью интерфейса.

Comment: @user7860670 Я верно Вас понял: если мы подключаем protobuf в библиотеку А командой 'target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE ${PROTOBUF_LIB})' а библиотеку а в проект как 'target_link_libraries(Project PRIVATE A)', то во-первых в Project не будет необходимости подключать protobuf для работы библиотеки А. Во-вторых, при независимой работе проекта Project с протобуф другой версии конфликтов двух версий не возникнет?

Comment: Нет, это произойдет, если линковать в A статическую библиотеку protobuf.